# Limit of workers in future::plan() function higher than available CPUs cores

Tags: r, future, furrr

I have a CPU of 8 cores which I'm trying to use to do parallel future_map_chr().
My question is as follows: the number of cores in my computer is equal to 8, so how is it possible to parallelize function with plan set as :

```
plan(multisession, workers = 50,gc=T)
```

Did I misunderstood the difference between workers and cores ? Is it better than `workers = detectCores()` ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Author of the [Futureverse](https://futureverse.org) here:

> Is it better than `workers = detectCores()`?

I argue that `parallelly::availableCores()` is better and safer than `parallel::detectCores()`, e.g. https://www.jottr.org/2022/12/05/avoid-detectcores/.

Using:

```
plan(multisession)
```

is the same as:

```
plan(multisession, workers = parallelly::availableCores())
```

However, there is nothing in the Futureverse and `plan()` that prevents you from going over the limit by specifying `workers` manually, e.g.

```
plan(multisession, workers = 50)
```

So, yes, this will spin up 50 parallel workers in the background, even if you only got 8 CPU cores on your machine.

I guess I could add some kind of protection when one tries to set up more than `parallelly::availableCores()` local workers. For instance, it could throw an informative error.  For anyone who wishes to override that, I could add an argument `force = TRUE`.  I've created https://github.com/HenrikBengtsson/parallelly/issues/107 to track this idea.